# How to create the chip UI inside a auto-complete-text-view in android?

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-chips

Can anyone give me the xml or any way to implement this kind of UI in android auto complete textview. Chip UI like this.

https://www.google.co.in/design/spec/components/chips.html#

Please note that I want to use CustomAdapter with the autocomplete textview.
Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing really built into Android to do this directly. You may wish to examine some of [the existing libraries for this](http://android-arsenal.com/search?q=chips) and see if you can adapt them for your purpose.

Comment: I tried the same, but when I use https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable with that class, drawable is not working properly.